# Post link subdomain WordPress

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, blogs

I have a site example.com and 1 post titled "Hello World" and `hello-world` as a permalink. So, any visitor can access at `example.com/hello-world` or `example.com/permalink`.

How can I change `example.com/hello-world` to `subdomain.example.com/hello-world` and apply that to all posts? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This consist of two settings. One in wordpress and a setting in the webserver.

In Wordpress you can configure the base url of your website. The domain itself is configured on the webserver and possibly on your domainname hosting.

**Update:**

What you want to do is to change the site url from `example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`.

I found that [this source](http://%20https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-How-do-I-change-the-WordPress-Site-URL-) is pretty good about explaining it how to configure the site url in Wordpress. Keep in mind that you also need to change the webserver. It depends per webserver how to configure it.

Comment: can you explain how to do that or is there plugin wordpress?